# Error bindParam(); PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

Para esta clase Conexion...

```
  class Conexion{
    private $host;
    private $user;
    private $pass;
    private $bbdd;
    private $connect;

    public function __construct(){
      $this->host = "localhost";
      $this->user = "usuario";
      $this->pass = "";
      $this->bbdd = "test";
      $this->connect = new mysqli();
    }

    public function connectBD(){
      $this->connect->connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->bbdd);
    }

    public function getConexion(){
      return $this->connect;
    }
```

*Realizo una sencilla tarea de añadir datos a mi BD, importo el archivo e inicializo el objeto **Conexion**.*

```
require("Conexion.php");
        $conexion = new Conexion();
        $conexion->connectBD();

        $connect = $conexion->getConexion();
```

Inserto un dato

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO test(id, nombre) VALUES(:id, :nombre)";

                    $stmt = $connect->prepare($sql);

                    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $_POST['id']);
                    $stmt->bindParam(':nombre', $_POST['nombre']);

                    $stmt->execute();
                    $stmt->close();
```

Y se produce un error que dice:

```
 Fatal error: Call to a member function bindParam() on boolean
```

Entiendo que el error dice que no se puede llarmar a la funcion bindParam() sobre un boolean lo que quiere decir que la variable $stmt llega como false al bindParam(); **luego se produce un error en el prepare**... pero ¿Que ocurre? Le he dado muchas vueltas y no hay manera.

Sin embargo si lo hago de esta forma... no hay ningun problema:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO test (id, nombre) VALUES (?, ?)";
                $stmt = $connect->prepare($sql);
                $stmt->bind_param("is", $_POST['id'], $_POST['nombre']);
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->close();
```

Comment: `bindParam` es PDO, `bind_param` es mysqli =P

Comment: Ya te dijeron en la respuesta la causa del error. En cuanto a la clase de conexión que estás usando es muy mejorable. Por ejemplo, ¿qué diferencia habría entre tu método `connectBD` y `getConexion`? ¿Por qué en el constructor de la clase creas  una instancia vacía de `mysqli`, teniendo a mano las credenciales para crear de una buena vez un objeto `mysqli` totalmente operativo? Creo que deberías refinar tu clase, así evitarías tener que escribir **tres líneas de código** cada vez que la necesitas.

Answer (score 1):

Ampliando el comentario `MySQLI` no soporta parámetros con nombre, `PDO` si.

Es por eso que el prepare devuelve false.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO test(id, nombre) VALUES(:id, :nombre)";
$stmt = $connect->prepare($sql);
```

sería válido si `$connect` fuera un `PDO`, y entonces podrías hacer:

```
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $_POST['id']);
```

en `MySQLI` la segunda forma funciona porque usa los placeholders (`?`) y además llamas al método correcto (`bind_param`)

Comment: Vale, Gracias por la respuesta si confundí PDO con MYSQLI en cuanto a lo de mejorar la clase conexión perfecto cierto que me puedo ahorrar algunas cosas. Gracias.